# Does Google Crawl Iframe ? - SEO

Tags: wordpress, seo

I am developing an Affiliate Marketing Website using Wordpress. As per the SEO Policies, we have put `rel="nofollow"` to all the affiliate links on my site.

However, there is an Amazon Search Widget which is placed as a Plugin on my site. It contains some Affiliate Links to Amazon. Also, it is placed in an `IFRAME`.

All I wanted to know is that..does google crawl `IFRAMES` ?? If yes, will google penalise my website ranking if I do not add a `rel="nofollow"` Tag in the IFRAME that contains the affiliate links ?

If yes, please advice how do I put a `rel="nofollow"` tag inside javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

M_Emamian

I believe in the old days `iframes` where pretty much ignored by google however, I have read that they now do indeed see the contents. However they also understand the content is not yours so any SEO value is past onto the originator of the content, after all they know where the content is being sourced from via the src on the `iframe`.

It's only my belief as I have not tested it but I have seen in a couple of videos that a `iframe` neither helps or harms you as far as SEO is concerned.

If however you really want to add a nofollow to the `iframe` then what you need to do is create a new page with just the `iframe` on it then add in the meta tags `<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">`

Once done add a `iframe` on your normal page which points to the new page with the `iframe` on it.

It's a little long winded but that should work.